# How can I connect to an Azure SQL database with .NET Framework project?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, azure-sql-database, .net-framework-version

I can't connect to my Azure SQL database with my .NET framework project.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Context" 
         connectionString="Data Source= .......database.windows.net; Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog= TestDB; uid={username}; Password={Password}; "   
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I try this. But it failed.

Comment: How do you failed?

Answer (score 0):

The connection string in your configuration file seems to be using SQL Server Authentication with a username and password. However, the Integrated Security=true attribute suggests that you may be trying to use Windows Authentication.

Integrated Security: When false, User ID and Password are specified in the connection. When true, the current Windows account credentials are used for authentication.

To connect to Azure SQL Database using SQL Server Authentication with a username and password, you should modify your connection string as follows

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="Context" 
    connectionString="Data Source=your_server_name.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=your_database_name;User ID=your_user_name@your_server_name;Password=your_password" 
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Seel the following documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0